# REST URI's and caching for GET requests when the list to be returned depends on the rights of the user

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, rest, microservices

1. It is a **multi-tenant serverless** system.
2. The system has groups with permissions.
3. Users derive permissions based on the groups they are in.
4. If it makes a difference, we are using Cognito for authentication and it is a stateless application.

For example:

1. GET endpoint for sites   (so sites that the logged-in user has access to based on the groups they are in)
2. GET endpoint for devices  (so sites that the logged-in user has access to based on the groups they are in)

In REST APIs. "The idea is that the data returned by an endpoint should depend solely on the parameters passed meaning two different users should receive the same result for the identical request.
"

What should the REST URI look like to ensure the above-stated idea? Since the deciding factor for the list here is "groups" and thus effective permissions, I was thinking we could pass the groups a user in, in the URI in sorted order to leverage caching on GET endpoints as well, Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: From where this quote from? The requests aren't identical, the Authorization header/cookie is different.

Comment: @Michael: It's an AWS serverless application,  Cognito user pool is used for authentication so there is no cookie or session. It's completely stateless.

Comment: What do you mean stateless? The application server must identify the user via token of something

Comment: yeah, we get idToken from the user pool when the user autenticates. It has nothing to do with permissions of the user @Michael

Comment: It is if you send the `idToken` to `GET sites`  endpoint, it adds some information to the request (user id, etc) which let the application server knows groups of which user it needs to fetch.

Comment: @Michael At the API gateway level though, if the caching is to be enabled, it won't be only for a request with the given JWT token right? It would just depend on the endpoint, path parameters, and query parameters. is that not so?

Comment: `What should the REST URI look like` The actual spelling of the URI is not of importance in a REST architecture. REST should build up on standardized media types/representation formats and use link-relation to decouple the lookup of the next possible action from the actual URI.

Comment: @RomanVottner Thanks. Would be great if you could be more specific in regards to the example in the question.

Comment: I think this will complicate the flow with no gain. anyway, not sure how the cache is relevant here. let me sure understand, you have, for example, a `GET sites` endpoint that returns user's sites based on its permission. the permissions stored in the server, which means the user doesn't need to send them to the server because the server knows who makes the request and can fetch the user's permissions by itself, right?

Answer (score 2):

> In REST APIs. "The idea is that the data returned by an endpoint should depend solely on the parameters passed meaning two different users should receive the same result for the identical request. "

No this is not strictly true. It can be a desirable property, but absolutely not needed. In fact, if you build a proper hypermedia REST api, you would likely want to hide links/actions that the current user is not allowed to use.

Furthermore, a cache will never store responses and send to different users if an `AUthorization` header is present on the request.

Anyway, there could be other reasons to want this.. maybe it's a simpler design for your case, and there is a pretty reasonable solution.

What I'm inferring from your question is that you might have two endpoints:

```
/sites
/devices
```

They return different things depending on who's accessing. Instead of using those kind of routes, you could just do:

```
/user/1234/sites
/user/1234/devices
```

Now every user has their own separate 'sites' and 'devices' collection. The additional benefit is that if you *ever* want to let a user find the list of sites or devices from *another* user, the API is ready to support that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. We have separate services for sites and devices. Would this still be the right thing to do? using the user base in different services? Also, can this cache be defeated when a new site/device is added? If so, would it be explicitly calling the GET API gateway to defeat cache from put sites/device

Comment: @SKhurana what the 'right' thing here is not that important. You should design your system in a way that makes sense for your situation. How your cache behaves depends on how you configure it.

Answer (score 2):

> The idea is that the data returned by an endpoint should depend solely
> on the parameters passed

This is called the statelessness constraint, but if you check the parameters always include auth parameters because of this. The idea is keeping the session data on the client side, because managing sessions becomes a problem when you have several million users and multiple servers all around the world. Since the parameters include auth data, the response can depend on this data, so you can use here the exact same endpoints for users with different permissions.

As of the responses you might want to send back hyperlinks, which represent the available operations. The concept is the same here, if the user does not have permission for the actual operation, then they won't get a hyperlink for that operation and in theory they should never get a 403 status either, because you must follow the hyperlinks you got from the service instead of hardcoding URI templates into your client. So you have to handle less errors and junk requests, and another reason here that you can change your URI templates without breaking the clients. This is called hypermedia as the engine of application state, it is part of the uniform interface constraint.

Comment: I see what you are saying about having only the endpoint URIs that a user has access to. Sounds great. It can also be achieved with an identity pool in cognito and then whitelisting the allowed endpoints for a user. However, what I was getting at is the endpoint being accessible to everyone but having a different response based on the permission. Are you suggesting that groups should be in the URI or not? I am Sorry I couldn't get an exact response for my doubt.

Comment: @SKhurana You can have different response based on the permissions. Just be careful what cache settings you use. If your clients follow the links they get, then from their perspective the structure of the URI does not matter. It can be even `/api/v1/1353745874` too. From developer and logging perspective it might be important, so I think it is your choice what kind of URI templates you use. I would not add groups to the URIs if the operations you want to access can overlap between groups. If they don't, then you can even make one REST API for each group, sort of microservices.